# How to debug Pubnub in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

**How to debug Pubnub in ruby on rails?**

**Case** - When result coming , debugger is not going to stop at callback.Is there any way to debug this except debugger?

Initialize code:

```
$pubnub ||= Pubnub.new(
  subscribe_key: Setting.subscribe_key,
  publish_key: Setting.publish_key,
  logger: Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/pubnub_logger.log")
)
#Add a global listener
$pubnub.add_listener(name: 'broadcast_listener', callback: Pubnub::PubnubService.new.callbacks)
```

Subscribe and Publish:

```
def subscribe(channel)
    # @my_callback = lambda { |envelope| puts("----------------->"+ envelope.msg) }
    $pubnub.subscribe(channel: channel)            
  end

  def publish(channel, message = {})
    # @my_callback = lambda { |envelope| puts("-------->From chat:: "+envelope.msg) }
    # pubnub.publish(:channel  => channel, :message  => msg, :callback => @my_callback )            
    puts "--------------Message---#{message}-------------------"
    $pubnub.publish(http_sync: true, channel: channel, message: message) do |envelope|
      puts envelope.status
    end
  end
```

Here is my callback:

```ruby
def callbacks 
    callbacks = Pubnub::SubscribeCallback.new(message: ->(envelope) { 
            # puts "#{envelope.result[:data]}" 
            subscription_callback(envelope.result) 
        }, 
        presence: ->(envelope) { 
            # puts #{envelope.result[:data][:message]}" 
            presence_callback(envelope.result) 
        }, 
        status: ->(envelope) {
            # show status
        } 
    ) 
end


def subscription_callback(result) 
    puts "----------------#{result}--------------" 
    binding.pry 
    parse_channel_name = result[:data][:subscribed_channel].split("_") 
    channel_name, broadcast_id = parse_channel_name[0], parse_channel_name[1] 
end
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code and show where you are trying to set breakpoint and any other details that might be helpful?

Comment: Here is my callback: 

def callbacks
    callbacks = Pubnub::SubscribeCallback.new(
    message:  ->(envelope) { 
      # puts "#{envelope.result[:data]}"
      subscription_callback(envelope.result)
    },
    presence: ->(envelope) { 
      # puts #{envelope.result[:data][:message]}"
      presence_callback(envelope.result) 
    },
    status:   ->(envelope) {
      #
    }
    ) 
  end

Comment: def subscription_callback(result)
  puts "----------------#{result}--------------"
  binding.pry
  parse_channel_name = result[:data][:subscribed_channel].split("_")
  channel_name, broadcast_id = parse_channel_name[0], parse_channel_name[1]
end

Comment: @CraigConover In subscription callback I am using pry as a breakpoint but it is not going to stop there.

Comment: What is **pry**? And you should edit your question and add the code using `code formatting`.

Comment: Pry is debugger here that is used  in rails as a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `pry`.
I did my best formatting your code but it is not the sort of Ruby code I've seen before, but I am not a Ruby expert. Please correct as necessary. I think we need to see your complete code that involves PubNub: like where you init PubNub (redact your keys, please) and such.